# Grouping a column to show specific answer

Tags: python, pandas, csv, multiple-columns, group

*CSV not provided

`instacart_orders.csv`: each row corresponds to one order on the Instacart app

`'order_id'`: ID number that uniquely identifies each order

`'user_id'`: ID number that uniquely identifies each customer account

`'order_number'`: the number of times this customer has placed an order

`'order_dow'`: day of the week that the order placed (which day is 0 is uncertain)

`'order_hour_of_day'`: hour of the day that the order was placed

`'days_since_prior_order'`: number of days since this customer placed their previous order

Hi everyone. I am having trouble coming up with a code to group 2 columns with a dataframe specifically. the question is....

```
"Check for all orders placed Wednesday at 2:00 AM"
```

my Code so far is

```
def new_label(day):
      if day == 0:
      return 'Monday'
  if day == 1:
      return 'Tuesday'
  if day == 2:
      return 'Wednesday'
  if day == 3:
      return 'Thursday'
  if day == 4:
      return 'Friday'
  if day == 5:
      return 'Saturday'
  if day == 6:
      return 'Sunday'
df_orders['order_dow'] = df_orders['order_dow'].apply(new_label)
print(df_orders['order_dow'])
```

This code let me label the #s to a specific DAY.
The code doesnt have to be 100% written I just need to know what to use and how to use it???

Comment: tip: you might want the list instead of the multiple if /el loops.

Comment: what format is the 'order_hour_of_day' in?  So what would 2am look like ? `02:00` or `2` ?

Comment: `df_orders[(df_orders['order_dow'] == 'Monday') & (df_orders['order_hour_of_day'] == 2)]`